# Retrieving "CanvasContent1" in JSON format

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-experience, sitepages

I'm trying to build my knowledge of SharePoint Restful API so that we can ultimately script bulk updates to pages.

Something I don't understand is why the "CanvasContent1" column is being returned as HTML when I use this command:

```
GET https://{{my_site}}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site%20Pages')/items(21)
```

and in JSON when I use this command:

```
GET  https://{{my_site}}/_api/sitepages/pages/GetById(21)
```

From what I can understand the `/sitepages/` request is actually part of the SP client API and not directly a RESTful call.  But there is very little documentation available.

Answer (score 1):

When adding web parts to a modern site page in SharePoint Online, the HTML content is saved into a column called `CanvasContent1`.

So, the `CanvasContent1` field contains a bunch of HTML data about the contents of the page. This includes web parts and their configuration including properties.

If you want to get this column as a text then you need to use below endpoint:

```
GET https://{{my_site}}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site%20Pages')/items(21)/FieldValuesAsText
```

Comment: Also, If you want to get all fields as HTML then you can use: `https://{{my_site}}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site%20Pages')/items(4)/FieldValuesAsHtml`

Comment: When updating a page via RESTful API should the ```CanvasContent1``` field be submitted as HTML  or JSON?

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3526), here they are using HTML value to update `CanvasContent1` field.