# How to get the site's html in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-experience, site-collection, administration

I want to use REST API to get the site's HTML in SharePoint.

For example: https://demo.sharepoint.com/sites/siteDemo.

Can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you cannot get the HTML for whole SharePoint site using SharePoint REST API. But you can get the HTML content of specific SharePoint site page using API call like:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/work/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items(1)/FieldValuesAsHtml?$select=CanvasContent1
```

Where `1` is the item ID of page from "Site Pages" library.

Check below threads for more information:

1. [How to retrieve the whole content of a modern SharePoint site page using the SharePoint API or Microsoft Graph API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/307632/how-to-retrieve-the-whole-content-of-a-modern-sharepoint-site-page-using-the-sha/307633#307633)
2. [Retrieving "CanvasContent1" in JSON format](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/288669/retrieving-canvascontent1-in-json-format/288671#288671)
3. [API to read text content of SharePoint site page](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/api-to-read-text-content-of-sharepoint-site-page/m-p/3576659)

Comment: thanks for answer, but i want to know homepage of site. But It seems like the home page has been renamed so I use /_api/web?$select=Welcome Page to only get the old homepage name. :(

Comment: When you use the REST API endpoint like mentioned [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/310547/how-to-find-the-home-page-of-a-site-i-want-to-use-the-rest-api-or-the-classic-i), you should get the name of latest home page of the site. Can you try running the API endpoint again now?

Comment: Hi, what would be the reason if I get the homepage but when I go to the site's page list I don't see that name?

Comment: Is your site pages view filtered based on any condition? Check the view settings for filters.

Comment: There is a property in the siteContext in all SharePoint page that called "isWebWelcomePage". Its a flag that you will know that the page that you are currently on is the HomPage of the Site.

I got the info from here 
https://tipsbybits.com/other/actually-its-already-in-the-sharepoint-pagecontext/